# C# remove an int from a List<int>

Tags: c#, list

I have a list of integers:

```
var list = new List<int>();
list.Add(1);
list.Add(1);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(3);
list.Add(3);
list.Add(2);
list.Add(2);
```

and I want to remove for example all the 1's in the list, I've used this:

```
list.RemoveAll(x => list.contains(1));
```

but it removes everything from list, while I wanna remove only 1s, which makes the list with the count of 8 to become a list with count of 6.

Comment: As the answers below point out, `list.contains(1)` is clearly not the test you're looking for; however, it's interesting that it doesn't work. Assuming the list is traversed serially and in order, it seems like the list would no longer contain a 1 after the first two removes. I'd love to hear an explanation from someone as to why it doesn't work. Otherwise, someday maybe I'll get around to checking it myself :-)

Comment: @rileywhite It seems like all the checks are done before removing any of the items: https://dotnetfiddle.net/L3WJLC

Comment: And if you have the time, you can take a look at the [actual implementation here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/list.cs,82567b42bbfc416e,references).

Comment: @dcastro Interesting. Looks like it decides what to remove first and then removes it. During the decision step, the list contains all of its original elements. This is why `list.contains()` always returns `true`. Thanks for my daily edification :-)

Comment: Note - this works: `var list = new List<int> {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4};`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list.RemoveAll(item => item == 1);
```

Answer (score 17):

Your code currently reads: For each element in the list, remove it from the list *if the list contains "1"*. This condition is true for all elements, so all elements are removed from the list.

What you need to specify is: For each element in the list, remove it from the list *if that item is 1*.

```
list.RemoveAll(item => item == 1);
```

Answer (score 4):

change

```
list.RemoveAll(x => list.contains(1));
```

to

```
list.RemoveAll(x => x == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:-
list.RemoveAll(x=> x.Equals(1));